# Creating a static library from Facebook SDK

Tags: static

Please help me to do the following:
I need to create a separate static library project with Facebook SDK in it and connect it to my main project. Tried to search but cannot find the guide for Xcode 4.2 :( All help will be highly appriciated (links, advices whatever..) Thanks!